# slickgrid: color rows depending on data

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I use slickGrid with dataview and need to color rows (background) dependent on data in one column.

```
What function would I use?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grid.setCellCssStyles()` to set css styles for any cell. You could leverage this to color the entire row.